# Is tcp listener and tcp server same thing in c#?

Tags: c#, tcplistener, tcpserver

What is the difference between TCP listener and TCP server? I want to communicate with some devices using TCP/IP protocol and want PC to organize the communication by using C#.

Comment: Yes, a server listens for connections.  There's a TcpListener class in .NET, there is no TcpServer class.  The machine on the other end of the wire uses TcpClient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET class [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) implements a TCP server. That’s how the two terms are related. So if you want a TCP server in your application, use the `TcpListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you havent posted any specific context. i would refer you some tutorials you can use as a base for TCP communication in c#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/A-Complete-TCP-Server-Client-Communication-and-RMI

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5733/A-TCP-IP-Server-written-in-C

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/50259-tcp-client-connection/

the previous answer sites the difference.

Comment: Then Listener Socket provides a client socket to the connected client, right?